# How to call express JS code repo from serverless repo

Tags: node.js, angular, express, serverless, aws-serverless

In my project, there are multiple repositories that contain Angular code, Express JS code (node JS), and AWS serverless. In one functionality, I am getting 'userId' from Angular code to serverless. I need to perform some database operations using that 'userId', but DB operations code is written under the express code repo, so for this I need to call express JS code from serverless. So how can I call the express JS route from AWS serverless, which is in different repositories?

I am thinking of the below solution. Please share your feedback on the same

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Doesn't `express JS route` mean there is a public API created through express? Can't you just call that API from your lambda?

Answer (score 0):

Separate the common code and make it **lambda layer**, and share the lambda layer in both project/application.